# Activity inheritance not being recognized by android studio

Tags: android, xml, inheritance

I just recently started learning android development, and decided to follow the [stanford public lectures](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs193a/videos.shtml) from winter 2017 on the matter. On lecture 3, they share a library that is an utility for quicker, cleaner code, found at [their page](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs193a/lib/).

I followed instructions and imported it. It is working and I really like the way it simplifies code. The thing is, that it does it by creating a class that extends AppCompatActivity and improves on it.

The class is called SimpleActivity and is declared as

```
public abstract class SimpleActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener, ... {
```

So, as far as I undestand, the class SimpleActivity is also an activity and should be recognized as one. I then create a new activity by

```
import stanford.androidlib.SimpleActivity;

public class DeadlyActivity extends SimpleActivity {

public void deadlyMethod(View view)
{
    //dostuff
}

}
```

Everything goes fine up until here, but when I go to the XML layout file, it does not recognize this class (DeadlyActivity) as a valid activity when I try to link an OnClick event to a class method like you do with any other activity.

```
<Button
    ...
    android:onClick="deadlyMethod"
>
```

It just says "Cannot resolve symbol 'deadlyMethod'". I find this odd as I thought it was just a simple reference to a method, but android seems to disagree, even while I can start DeadlyActivity as an activity AND the method WORKS despite the warning.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DeadlyActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
//this works, being summoned from MainActivity, which is a plain AppCompatActivity
```

Further problems arise when trying to use the keyword "this" when required to use an activity as an argument, since it does not recognize the class as such.

I just made a simple test, made DeadlyActivity inherit from AppCompatActivity, and then made a new class called FuriousActivity that inherits from DeadlyActivity and it WORKS. Why does the library way not work?

Am I missing something? Do I not understand inheritance? Is my android studio cursed?

Comment: Did you see the 'r'? SimplerActivity extends SimpleActivity

Comment: Yeah, ive tried with several classes and tried implementing my own class that inherits from AppCompatActivity with same results

Comment: Someplace in the code you have an item declared as SimpleActivity instead of SimplerActivity (with an r).  Only properties declared as SimplerActivity (with r) will have the method simpleMethod.

Comment: It shouldnt even be an issue; the layout file even shows me the methods from other activities, but not those ones that I try to inherit from the class. The name doesnt really matter but people seem fixated on that detail. I checked it: "andoid:context=".SimplerActivity"". Made another class, DeadlyActivity, same results. Everything is declarated properly on Manifest, and I still see no good reason why I cant inherit an activity class and make it behave as such.

Comment: I just made a simple test, made DeadlyActivity inherit from AppCompatActivity, and then made a new class called FuriousActivity that inherits from DeadlyActivity and it WORKS. Why does the library not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is linked to the library itself, since some of its imports are invalid either because of the current iteration of android or by the lack of repos on my end. Only when reading thru the declaration of the java code instead of the compiled version, the errors will show up, as android studio will not warn about any of them. The class "SimpleActivity" is just unable to resolve "AppCompatActivity" because of broken imports and therefore, is unable to work properly.

It is a bit sad, but I'll have to recomend against using this library unless you are able to solve the imports on it and double check it still works as intended.